# StructureMap: how to specify a Ctor argument by type instead of name

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'd like to override the default SessionFactory instance for one of my repositories. I used the following code to achieve this but I'm not fond of having to specify the name of the constructor argument I'm trying to override.

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For(typeof(IRepository<Facility>))
        .Use(typeof(Repository<Facility>))
            .CtorDependency<ISessionFactory("sessionFactory")
                .IsNamedInstance("CoolSessionFactory");
});
```

The SM documentation suggests that, so long as the ctor doesn't take more than one argument of the same type, then `CtorDependency` method doesn't require that you provide the parameter name. However, using the latest version of SM, I see no such overload of `CtorDependency`. Is there a different configuration option that can achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Child<>` instead of `CtorDependency<>`

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For(typeof(IRepository<Facility>))
        .Use(typeof(Repository<Facility>))
            .Child<ISessionFactory>()
                .IsNamedInstance("CoolSessionFactory");
});
```